# viewdidload of second view taking time for call that is push from first view by collection view & table view didselect

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, iosdeployment

I am tried to search & solve this problem please any one give solution of this problem.
Actually, i am using **collection view** & also **table view** in my app but in case of **push** to other view by **didselect** of both view(collection view & also table view) **viewdidload** of 2nd view take time for call. I have also check out by break point didselect call suddenly but viewdidload of 2nd view take time for call than start working of 2nd view.

**"Code of didselect"**

```
let dict = self.arr.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSMutableDictionary

let 2ndview = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("2ndview") as! viewcontroller
2ndview.dict = dict

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(2ndview, animated: true)
```

**"Code of 2nd viewdidload"**
**viewdidload**

tbl.delegate = self

tbl.dataSource = self

tbl.separatorStyle = .None

btn.hidden = true

tf.delegate = self

Comment: it is possible that your push request is on main thread and some other process is getting executed on main thread before your call. @Anil Kumar Patil

Comment: are you doing some heavy task in viewdidload, like calling API?

Comment: sir Kar, i have try main thread by dispatch but didn't work

Comment: sir Mr.UB i have try that also all code comment on view didload also on will appare but that also didn't work

Comment: Are you doing any heavy data processing or api calls in viewWillDisappear of 1st viewcontroller or ViewWillAppear method in second view controller ? Check what is happening after the didSelect method is finished executing by adding some breakpoints.

Comment: sir  Manishankar i m not using  viewWillDisappear

Comment: Code of view did load of 2nd class
        tbl.delegate = self
        tbl.dataSource = self
        tbl.separatorStyle = .None
        btn.hidden = true
        tf.delegate = self

Comment: @AnilKumarPatil have you any done any other stuff in the initializers?

Answer (score 0):

i think you have some memory issue so check your memory uses while you change controller . and in your build setting Code Generation optimize level value is fastest or not ? check this .